# NSURLRequest HTTPBody is null

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, nsurlrequest, nsurlsession

I've been trying to send POST requests to a server (which I know works from using Postman) using `NSURLSession`.

I create a request as follows:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self createRequestWithPath:[self getPathForEndpoint:endpoint]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:params];
```

`params` is created from a serialised parameter string (which I know is a legal parameter string), as follows:

```
NSData *params = [[self serialiseParameters:data] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

(For reference, the serialised parameter string is something like `@"title=MyTitle&somethingElse=0"`.

From searching around SO and other places, this seems like this is the correct way to set up the request such that `NSURLSession` can POST the data, but the server is showing nothing coming through in the HTTP Body.

Is there another way to POST data?

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by not using the setters `setHTTPBody` at all, and using `NSJSONSerialization` instead. The working code looks like this:

```
// Encode parameters
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:data options:0 error:nil];

// Construct request
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self createRequestWithPath:[self getPathForEndpoint:endpoint]];
request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
request.HTTPBody   = postData;
```

I had tried using this before, but for some reason it didn't work properly when I used `[request setHTTPBody]`, setting the property directly solved this.

Comment: There is no difference between `setHTTPBody:` and `.HTTPBody =` that could cause the former not to work. Something was up with `- (NSString *)serialiseParameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters`.

Comment: I checked the parameters, and they come out as I would expect them to (but am now just using it for GET parameters instead).